# KAFKA : find partition of message published?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have published a message using 
KeyedMessage data = new KeyedMessage("topic",partition_key, msg);

How to recheck whether message went to which partition ?

Comment: what kafka version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `send()` with the `KeyedMessage`, a `Future<RecordMetadata>` is returned. Use `RecordMetadata.partition()` to get the partition. `offset()` returns the offset. See here:

http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/RecordMetadata.html

Comment: how to access Future<RecordMetadata> ?

Comment: See the javadoc for how to work with a Future: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: i am trying Future<RecordMetadata> fet = producer.send(data);